# Deformation in the nematic phase of a liquid crystal survived in solid state

Tags: condensed-matter, phase-transition, crystals, soft-matter, liquid-crystal

Does anyone know if I cool a liquid crystal with a deformed nematic phase quickly it will preserve the deformation in the crystal lattice? I didn't never see that in classical books on liquid crystals.

Comment: I think that's worth an actual experiment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the deformation, I yet not know but the order is kept (see bellow).

*GLASSY LIQUID-CRYSTALS - OBSERVATION OF A QUENCHED TWISTED NEMATIC
Por: KESSLER, JO; RAYNES, EP
PHYSICS LETTERS A  Volume: A 50   Edição: 5   Páginas: 335-336   Publicado: 1974

*
Stripe patterns in the magnetic reorientation of a glass-forming nematic liquid crystal
Por: Grigutsch, M; Stannarius, R
EUROPEAN PHYSICAL JOURNAL E  Volume: 8   Edição: 4   Páginas: 365-372   Publicado: JUL 2002
Context Sensitive Links Texto integral do editor
Visualizar resumoVisualizar resumo
Número de citações: 1
(de todas as bases de dados)

*
FAST-COOLED LIQUID-CRYSTALS
Por: ROSTA, L
MOLECULAR CRYSTALS AND LIQUID CRYSTALS  Volume: 127   Edição: 1-4   Páginas: 195-213   Publicado: 1985
Context Sensitive Links
Número de citações: 10
(de todas as bases de dados)

*
SPECTROSCOPIC AND THERMODYNAMIC INVESTIGATIONS OF THE POLYMORPHISM OF THE SOLID-STATE OF LIQUID-CRYSTALS
Por: KIROV, N; FONTANA, MP; CAVATORTA, F
JOURNAL OF MOLECULAR STRUCTURE  Volume: 59   Edição: JAN   Páginas: 147-160   Publicado: 1980
Context Sensitive Links Texto integral do editor
Número de citações: 11
(de todas as bases de dados)

*
DETERMINATION OF ORIENTATIONAL ORDER PARAMETER S2 IN GLASSY LIQUID-CRYSTALS BY MEANS OF IR DICHROISM
Por: KIROV, N; FONTANA, M
MOLECULAR CRYSTALS AND LIQUID CRYSTALS  Volume: 56   Edição: 6   Páginas: 195-202   Publicado: 1980
Context Sensitive Links
Número de citações: 16
(de todas as bases de dados)

*
INVESTIGATION OF POLYMORPHISM IN MBBA BY POSITRON-ANNIHILATION
Por: WALKER, WW
APPLIED PHYSICS  Volume: 16   Edição: 4   Páginas: 433-434   Publicado: 1978
Context Sensitive Links
Número de citações: 9
(de todas as bases de dados)

- TRANSITION OF AN ORIENTED NEMATIC LIQUID-CRYSTAL TO A GLASS WITH A NEMATIC ORDER - DETERMINATION OF ORDER PARAMETER
  Por: POGGI, Y; ALEONARD, R; ROBERT, J
  PHYSICS LETTERS A  Volume: 54   Edição: 5   Páginas: 393-395   Publicado: 1975